# Chat Application using UITableView Vs UIcollectionView (iOS)?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview, chat, whatsapp

I am going to develop a chat application. but my concern is if i should go for UITableView or UICollectionView for that bubble chat view like in whatsapp.

Given below is screenshot of WhatsApp Chat. If anyone Know what WhatsApp used for this Screen?

```
  UITableView or UICollectionView??????
```

[image: Whatsapp chat screenshot]

Comment: check here it is used UICollectionview: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController

Comment: Hi Nitin, Thanks for a quick reply. I downloaded the code but there are three errors like some file missing.                           diff: /../Podfile.lock: No such file or directory
diff: /Manifest.lock: No such file or directory
error: The sandbox is not in sync with the Podfile.lock. Run 'pod install' or update your CocoaPods installation.

Comment: this is cocoapods demo you need to install this demo via cocoaPods brother

Comment: Bro, i just look at the cocoaPods. If it is software to be installed in mac. I did not get much.

Comment: Please see my post http://www.digifloor.com/install-cocoapods-xcode-project-4-simple-steps-06 of how to install cocoaPods @Gagan

Comment: Hi  @GaganJoshi , finally used which one? tableView or collectionView ? :-)

Answer (score -3):

You should use UITableView, and for bubbles like whatsapp, there is an API

- https://github.com/ppanopticon/PTSMessagingCell/

Comment: 10 commits 2 years ago. Have you used this?

Comment: It also uses to 2 depreciations in iOS 7.

Comment: https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController good one as reference to read as its updated library always.